# How make a SSH tunnel from one computer to another and forward its traffic?

Tags: port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, jboss

I have two computers both running Linux. Let's call them computer A and computer B. Computer A has IP 192.168.1.10 and B has 192.168.1.11.

On computer B there is a JBoss 7 AS installed and its admin interface is just accessable locally (on `http://127.0.0.1:9990`) and I would like to access it from computer A.

Therfor I would like to SSH tunnel to computer B from computer A and forward all traffic to another port that is open on B, let's say I would forward incomming HTTP requests on port 8081 on B to 127.0.0.1:9990.

How can I establish such a tunnel from computer A to computer B?

I followed this guide but failed: http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On computer A:

```
ssh -fCNL 8081:localhost:9990 username@192.168.1.11
```

Or reverse port forward from computer B (don't use both simultaneously):

```
ssh -fCNR 9990:localhost:8081 username@192.168.1.10
```

For understanding the options see `man ssh`

Comment: Thanks! I will try that tomorrow at work. Will accept the answer tomorrow if I succeed. :-)

Comment: On a normal network the -C option will just slow things down.

Comment: For me the CPU overhead from `-C` is negligible. Desktops and servers can handle gzip compression/decompression very easily and embedded devices usually turn off this feature. On the other size, network load is significantly lower especially on port forwarding (often is uncompressed/plaintext data).